# How to update Geth to Homestead (1.3.4)?

Tags: go-ethereum, homestead

How can u update geth to Homestead version? Found [this github](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.4) link, but there is nothing specified about installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just figured out that `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` will work if you followed the `ppa` way.

**OSX users using brew**

```
brew update && brew upgrade ethereum
```

## Update to [Release 1.3.5](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases) is recommended

Comment: You should also make sure you update to 1.3.5.  For OS X users:  brew update && brew upgrade ethereum

Answer (score 4):

They removed the binaries because there is already a [hotfix release 1.3.5](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.5) available.

**Upgrade geth to 1.3.5**.